# Android - Adapter wrong position

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

i set in OnClickListener change background icon:

```
        holder.rating_good.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.rating_good.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_red);
                apiMethods.ChangePostRating(ctx, String.valueOf(item.getId()), "up", holder.rating, holder.rating_good);
            }

        });

        holder.rating_bad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.rating_good.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_red);
                apiMethods.ChangePostRating(ctx, String.valueOf(item.getId()), "down", holder.rating, holder.rating_bad);
            }

        });
```

But in some item background changes, even if I do not press the button.
Standart background ImageView if this rating_good - R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_grey, if this rating_bad - R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_grey.

My getView:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);

            holder.rating_good = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageRatingGood);
            holder.rating_bad = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageRatingBad);
            holder.rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedRating);
            holder.rating.setTag(position);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

            try {

                item = feedItems.get(position);
                ctx = parent.getContext();

            holder.rating_good.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.rating_good.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_red);
                    apiMethods.ChangePostRating(ctx, String.valueOf(item.getId()), "up", holder.rating, holder.rating_good);
                }

            });

            holder.rating_bad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.rating_good.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_red);
                    apiMethods.ChangePostRating(ctx, String.valueOf(item.getId()), "down", holder.rating, holder.rating_bad);
                }

            });

            //OTHER SOME CODE

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Mint.logException(e);
                }

        return convertView;
    }

static class ViewHolder {
      TextView nickname;
      TextView date;
      TextView description;
      TextView rating;
      TextView type;
      FeedImageView feedImageView;
      ImageView rating_good;
      ImageView rating_bad;
      ImageView type_image;
      LinearLayout linear;
}
```

ApiMethods class:

```
public void ChangePostRating(Context new_ctx, String id, String rate, TextView textview, ImageView rView) {
          ctx = new_ctx;
          token = pref.GetToken(ctx);
          content_id = id;
          rating_string = rate;
          url = apiUrl.GetUrlChangeRating();
          app_id = info.app_key;
          myView = textview;
          imageButton = (ImageView) rView;

          RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);
          StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String responses) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responses);
                        String status = response.getString("status");
                        if (!status.contains("error")) {
                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
                            int rating = data.getInt("rating");
                            TextView text_rating = (TextView)  myView;
                            text_rating.setText(String.valueOf(rating));
                            if (Integer.valueOf(text_rating.getText().toString()) < 0) {
                                text_rating.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.feed_item_rating_bad));
                            } else {
                                text_rating.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.feed_item_rating_good));
                            }
                        } else {
                            JSONObject error = response.getJSONObject("error");
                            String message = error.getString("message");
                            parseError(message);
                            if (rating_string.contains("up")) {
                                imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_grey);
                            } else {
                                imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_grey);
                            }

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Mint.logException(e);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Mint.logException(error);
                }
            });
           queue.add(sr);
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only subscribe to the event handlers once per view like below (untested since I typed it here but you get the idea). Subscribing to them multiple times will lead to issues due to the fact you're caching them (hence the use of ViewHolder).

Now whether or not this fixes your problem is another thing but it's still something you need to fix.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    if (convertView == null) {
        if (inflater == null)
           inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);

        holder.rating_good = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageRatingGood);
        holder.rating_bad = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageRatingBad);
        holder.rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedRating);

        holder.rating_good.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag()  
                viewHolder.rating_good.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_red);
                apiMethods.ChangePostRating(ctx, String.valueOf(viewHolder.item.getId()), "up", viewHolder.rating, viewHolder.rating_good);
            }
        });

        holder.rating_bad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag()  
               viewHolder.rating_good.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_green);
                apiMethods.ChangePostRating(ctx, String.valueOf(viewHolder.item.getId()), "down", viewHolder.rating, viewHolder.rating_bad);
            }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

        try {

            item = feedItems.get(position);
            ctx = parent.getContext();
            holder._rating_bad.setTag(holder);
            holder._rating_good.setTag(holder);
            holder.rating.setTag(position);
            holder._item = item;
        });

        //OTHER SOME CODE

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Mint.logException(e);
            }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Not work, always in feed some post change icon, even if I do not press the button

Comment: Updated it since there was another problem with your code. Try again with the updated code and see if that helps.

Comment: holder._rating_bad.setTag(holder); - maybe holder.rating_bad.setTag(holder); ? without "_" ?
I add my ViewHolder to fist post, see.

Comment: yep. do it without the _. As I said, I typed it here so it probably won't compile but make it compile by fixing the typos and hopefully it'll help.

Comment: not work, maybe trouble in apiMethods? I add to first post this class. I noticed that after like or dislike - it is repeated in the same order in which I set

Comment: Sure. I would suggest debugging your apiMethods (and even your adapter) to see what's going on. The code as is shouldn't exhibit the problems you're describing unless the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Make Log.d and publish?

Comment: Log.d is a great option. Do that together with using break points and inspecting the parameters.